# Javascript create DIV with var inside

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to show to user Text with variable inside, is that possible somehow since im injecting innerHTML?

```
  const price = document.querySelector("div.basket div.price em").innerText
  const nettoprice = price * 0.77
  div.className = "alert";
  div.innerHTML = "<div class="netto-print">
    Netto Price: $nettoprice
  </div>";

  document.body.append(div);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use **template literals**:

```
  div.innerHTML = `<div class="netto-print">
    Netto Price: ${nettoprice}
  </div>`;
```

For more information about how to handle texts check [Handling text by MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with backtick strings:

```
function escapeHTML(str){
    return new Option(str).innerHTML;
}

div.innerHTML = `<div>${escapeHTML(price)}</div>`
```